# How to see what jQuery object is selected in Chrome debugger?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I have this code:

```
var $currentImage = $("#hero div:first");
// code which changes $currentImage
```

And this html

```
    <div id="hero">
        <div class="current"><img src="img/1.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/2.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/3.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/4.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/5.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/6.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/7.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

When I add `$currentImage` to `Watch` I want to see what `img` `src` it has.
In Chrome debugger I see only tons of functions, no id, inner html or something. Even in `__proto__` there are only functions.

How to see what object is really selected?

Also why is next to `$currentImage` this: `jQuery.fin.init[1]`
It makes it seem like `$currentImage` is a function?

Comment: `$currentImage` is a jquery object.  jquery objects have a lot of functions which allow chaining etc.  You probably want `$currentImage.get(0)`

Comment: Can I add that expression as watch or do I need to type it into console after every step in debugger?

Comment: You can add it as a watch.  Or, if all you want is the `img` `src`, you could just watch `$currentImage.get(0).src`.